# How can i switch a magento store programatically with seo Url?

Tags: magento, url-routing, magento-1.8

How can i switch a magento store programatically with seo Url without creating seperate folder ?.

I have a storeController in my custom module.

Its not working perfectly. current store cookie value not changed because it automatically goes to default store when i go to homepage.

This is what i want ( i need really a store switch effect).

www.site.com/module/store/id/

My Store Controller

```
class Namespace_Module_StoreController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
 public function indexAction()
 {   
    // site.com/module/store/12-store1

    $id = explode('-',$this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
    $id = $id[0];

    $store = Mage::getModel( 'core/store' )->load($id); 

    $this->_title($this->__('Module'))->_title($store->getName());

    $rootCategoryId = $store->getRootCategoryId();

    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store->getStoreId()); 

    $this->loadLayout();   
    $this->renderLayout();
  }
}
```

Comment: are you want for particular module

Answer (score 0):

A controller would be far to deep to switch stores at this point. Store run codes can only be set when the application loads at bootstrap level (yes, `index.php`) and not at any point after (in which the controller dispatches are included).

Try your luck somewhere else.. A good solution is to use .htaccess to set the `MAGE_RUN_CODE` (to your desired store view) and `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` (to store/website) environment variables before bootstrapping ever happens.